# In Java (Pig) Regex, how could I do the following?

Tags: java, regex, apache-pig

I have data coming in a txt file delimited by pipes.  The unfortunate thing is 2 fields can have multiple values.  To separate these multiples, the sender used pipes again, but put quotes around it. My regex worked for months until a certain rare situation...

Regex currently:

```
([^\|]*)\|"?([^"]*)"?\|([^\|]*)\|"?([^"]*)"?
```

And it worked for the following situation which happens most of the time:
abc|"part1|part2"|abc|"tool1|tool2"

But this case is where the `([^"]*)` jumps ahead and takes all from the blank to the end of the quotes:
abc||abc|"tool1|tool2"

So I realize I must account for when there is a pipe next instead of a quote.
Just not sure how.............
P.S. For those PIG people that might be looking at this, I removed a backslash from each escape, to make it look more like Java, but in PIG you need 2, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

In your expression you need to specify that the part between `|`s can be either quoted or not quoted. You can do it as follows:

```
(("[^"]*")|((?!")[^|]*))
```

Now you can repeat this part several times with `|`s in between, as you need.

Comment: Thanks for your post axtavt, you were very close.  Just gotta get rid of some paren's. 
My friend helped me get it exactly:

     `code`([^\|]*)\|("[^"]*"|[^\|]*)\|([^\|]*)\|("[^"]*"|[^\|]*)`code`